# How to handle duplicate Xpath Appium Robotframework?

Tags: xpath, appium, robotframework

I have try to click on element but it's was duplicate xpath. and my purpose is want to click xpath in index [1] but by default it's click on xpath index [0].

I have try to count xpath with

```
${count}    Get Matching Xpath Count    //XCUIElementTypeTable[1]/XCUIElementTypeCell[1]/XCUIElementTypeStaticText[1]
Log To Console   ${count}
```

and i got result 2. I'm also take this xpath to search in Appium Inspect tool it's also display 2 result come up.
how to handle this ?

Comment: This might help you: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33422/how-to-find-the-first-occurrence-of-a-field-that-exists-in-multiple-places

Comment: thanks you, i found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
click element xpath=(//XCUIElementTypeTable[1]/XCUIElementTypeCell[1]/XCUIElementTypeStaticText[1])[2]
```